# SyntaxError with passing **kwargs and trailing comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-3.4

I wonder why this is a SyntaxError in Python 3.4:

```
some_function(
  filename = "foobar.c",
  **kwargs,
)
```

It works when removing the trailing comma after `**kwargs`.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue9232

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As pointed out by vaultah (who for some reason didn’t bother to post an answer), this was [reported on the issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue9232) and has been changed since. The syntax will work fine starting with Python 3.6.

> To be explicit, yes, I want to allow trailing comma even after `*args` or `**kwds`. And that's what the patch does. —[Guido van Rossum](http://bugs.python.org/issue9232#msg248449)

Answer (score 10):

The reason it was originally disallowed is because `**kwargs` was the last allowed item in an argument list -- nothing could come after it; however, a `,` looks like there could be more following it.

That has changed so that we can now call with multiple keyword dicts:

```
some_func(a, b, **c, **d,)
```

For consistency's sake, trailing commas are now supported in both definitions and callings of functions.  This is really useful when one has either several arguments, or a few long arguments, and so the logical line is split across several physical lines.

The trailing commas are optional in both locations.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious about the `**c, **d` part. How would Python know which keyword arguments to put in `c` and which in `d`?

Comment: @NiklasR: Sorry, had that part wrong, updated answer.